# Why do you overfit if you train a linear regression model on a dataset that doesn't have enough datapoints?

Tags: regression, linear, overfitting, bias-variance-tradeoff

First of all, definitionally speaking, linear regressions tend to underfit (have high bias, low variance).

Additionally, just intuitively speaking, it seems like a linear regression would underfit in this situation. But the answer seems to be overfit.

Eg. If i have a dataset of only 3 points (clearly not enough), and i fit a linear regression on it, wouldn't you get a line that **underfits**? (see poorly drawn picture below that represents the linear "model" I'd imagine getting).

The only case where I could see a linear regression overfitting on these 3 points is if they happened to land perfectly in a linear line?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find it totally plausible that your three points were generated by a downward-sloping trend and happened to have an especially high error term on the right-most point.

Maybe that’s not the most likely scenario, but that seems plausible, and if that is the case, your proposed regression line has overfit to an apparent upward trend.

If, instead of three points, you have ten or a thousand points, you get a better picture of the trend and are less likely to identify an upward trend when the true trend is downward.

**SIMULATION**

Let’s see how often an increasing relationship results in a negative regression slope for sample sizes of $3$, $10$, and $1000$.

```
set.seed(2023)
N1 <- 3
N2 <- 10
N3 <- 1000
R <- 1000
slopes1 <- slopes2 <- slopes3 <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
    
    x1 <- rnorm(N1)
    y1 <- x1 + rnorm(N1)
    L1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
    slopes1[i] <- summary(L1)$coef[2, 1]

    x2 <- rnorm(N2)
    y2 <- x2 + rnorm(N2)
    L2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2)
    slopes2[i] <- summary(L2)$coef[2, 1]

    x3 <- rnorm(N3)
    y3 <- x3 + rnorm(N3)
    L3 <- lm(y3 ~ x3)
    slopes3[i] <- summary(L3)$coef[2, 1]

}

ecdf(slopes1)(0) # 16% of slopes are negative for N = 3
ecdf(slopes2)(0) # 0.7% of slopes are negative for N = 10
ecdf(slopes3)(0) # No negative slopes for N = 1000
```

Analytically, it is the case that the standard errors of the regression coefficients shrink as the sample size increases, so the coefficient estimate variance decreases.

Comment: Yes you have validated my point even more! If even the direction of the trend is ambiguous, how can a linear regression overfit in this situation? It sounds like blatant underfitting to me...?

Comment: Oh i guess with each additional point the line switches direction, whereas if you had 10000 points and you added 100 more, the line would barely budge.

Comment: Imagine fitting to three points and then testing on many others. If the three points give a decreasing slope when the true trend is increasing, you will have poor out-of-sample performance. That is how the overfitting has happened: the estimation has picked up in a coincidence in the training data (a decreasing trend) instead of the true trend. This is much less likely to occur as the sample size increases. @Katsu

Comment: Yep totally got it now. With each additional point in tiny dataset, the line moves massively = overfits. Just like how a x^5 model would move massively with each new point = overfits. If you have 10K points in a linear reg, and added 500 more, the line would barely budge = underfits (well or just high bias here).

Comment: Underfitting is a separate issue. The linear model in my simulation, for instance, is a perfect model.

Answer (score 2):

Overfitting occurs when the error of a fitted model is dominated by the noise. (another source of error is bias)

In your case with only three points, the upperwards slope of the fitted linear line may easily be a wrong fit and the true pattern of the population, from which these three points are sampled, can be different.

[image: example of overfitting with 3 points]

Comment: I understand your point, but it is kind of counterintuitive for me. seems like it underfit at first glance.